# How can i create a Tile System like this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Container with Tiles]

So i am creating a ***Responsiv Website*** in which i want to have a Tile System like in the Image above. Unfortunatly i just cant get it done right.
Here is my current [ATTEMPT](https://jsfiddle.net/742jbaqr/2/). Using Flexbox

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -moz-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  background: #eaeaea;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flex-item:hover {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
.flex-item-stop {
  background: crimson;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flex-item-stop:hover {
  background-color: #bb1133;
}
#Menue {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 650px;
  float: right;
  padding: 25px 0;
  margin: -25px 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -moz-inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -moz-justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: column wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menue">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">Vanilla</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Citrus</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Bananasplit</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Gum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container" style="margin-top:10%;">
    <div class="flex-item">Sweden</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Austria</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Russia</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Brazil</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container" style="margin-top:10%;">
    <div class="flex-item">Positiv</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Negativ</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Neutral</div>
    <div class="flex-item-stop">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just cant create the spacing between the tiles and my result seems different in different browsers, especially in the Internet Explorer 11.
 What i also would like to have is that there should always be 4 Tiles in a singel "line" is this possible?

Now comes my Question: What exactly do i have to change in my Code to accomplish such a Tile System?
Are the alternatives to Flexbox?

Any Examples suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```css
.row{
display:table;
content:'';
clear:both;
width:100%;
}
.item{
box-sizing:border-box;
width:25%;
border:1px solid white;
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="item">Vanilla</div>
<div class="item">Gum</div>
<div class="item">Citrus</div>
<div class="item">BananaSplit</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a crack:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
    <!-- e.t.c... !-->
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.container > .inner-block{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(25% - 13px);
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: calc(25% - 13px);
    margin: 5px;
    background: blue;
}
```

**JsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/r4w1v0dm/2/